# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: processing.core.PVector.mult

Tags: processing

I am using the ComputationalGeometry library for processing http://www.thecloudlab.org/processing/library.html

and trying to run the IsoSurface example, but this error keeps on showing. How can I solve the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What exact line of code are you trying to run?

Comment: @ReemHA What version of Processing are you using ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza the latest version 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason there is an issue with the [PVector.mult(float)](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PVector.html#mult-float-) signature is in Processing 3 at the moment.

One option would be to use an alternative PVector method in IsoSufrace's plotVoxels() method and recompile the ComputationalGeometry library if you have no other option than using Processing 3.0

A more practical approach is to use an earlier stable version like [Processing 2.2.1](https://processing.org/download/?processing)